# Saber si hay registros y recorrerlos con PDO en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Soy nuevo con este tipo de consultas PDO, quiero ver si en una tabla hay al menos 1 registro, y recorrerlo. Lo habia hecho con FetchColumn, pero aunque encontraba más de un registro me mostraba todos menos uno.

En su reemplazo coloque rowCount y si me mostro los registros completos que cumplen con la conidición, pero no entendi bien cual es el mejor metodo. Gracias

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$resultado = $pdo->query("SELECT id, temperatura, humedad, date(fecha_hora) as fecha, time(fecha_hora) as hora FROM sensor_hyt WHERE date(fecha_hora)='$fecha' AND temperatura>='30.0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
if ($resultado->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo 'ALERTA ALERTA';
    foreach($resultado as $M3) {
    echo $M3['id'].'Temperatura: '.$M3['temperatura'].'Humedad:'.$M3['humedad'].' Fecha'.$M3['fecha'].' Hora '.$M3['hora'].'<hr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: a que te refieres con: **me mostraba todos menos uno**? pudieras colocar un ejemplo de como necesitas los datos y como los estabas obtendiendo?

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios problemas con tu código. Los enumero y te propongo una solución:

- Es inseguro, te pueden colar *inyección SQL* con suma facilidad. Lee sobre el tema cuando puedas.
- La consulta parece tener un error de sintaxis, al no separar las columnas `temperatura` y `id`: <s>`SELECT temperatura id, ...`</s>
- Dado que es una consulta con `LIMIT`, puedes usar `fetchAll` para guardar los resultados en una variable y luego probar esa variable directamente con un `if`. Si no arroja datos, esa variable será `FALSE`, no necesitas usar `rowCount` para saber si hay datos en este caso. Tu uso de `fetchColumn` tampoco era correcto para el caso, porque así puedes obtener solamente una columna. `fetchColum` es útil cuando el `SELECT` trae una sola columna (por ejemplo en consultas del tipo `COUNT(*)` donde únicamente interesa saber cuántas filas hay y nada más.
- En tu consulta hay más cosas dudosas. Por ejemplo, si en la base de datos `fecha_hora` es del tipo `DATETIME` no tiene sentido que lo conviertas a `date` y luego a `time` en el `SELECT` trayendo así un mismo dato dos veces convertido. Estás desperdiciando recursos, ancho de banda, memoria... ¿Por qué no traes el dato una sola vez y luego por programación lo muestras como `date` y como `time` (dentro del `for` creando un único objeto  `DateTime` y aplicando `format` a ese objeto)?  Dado que no estoy seguro del tipo de dato en la tabla no lo hice así. Si la columna es `DATETIME` optimizarás el código haciéndolo de este modo... No cambio eso en la propuesta de código porque no conozco el tipo de dato, lo dejo a tu consideración.
- Otra cosa que me deja dudoso es esta: `temperatura>='30.0'`. Estás usando una comparación del tipo *mayor o igual*  y poniendo el valor entre comillas simples. Si esa columna es de un tipo numérico como `DOUBLE` o `DECIMAL`  ... la comparación debe hacerse de este modo: `... temperatura >= 30.0`. No cambio eso en la propuesta de código porque no conozco el tipo de dato, lo dejo a tu consideración.
- Tampoco entiendo por qué repites dos veces `temperatura` en el `echo`  ¿?

Propuesta:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$sql="SELECT temperatura, id, humedad, date(fecha_hora) as fecha, time(fecha_hora) as hora FROM sensor_hyt WHERE date(fecha_hora)=? AND temperatura>='30.0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$mParams=array($fecha);
$stmt->execute($mParams);
$mData=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($mData) {
    $txtOutput= 'ALERTA ALERTA'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach($resultado as $M3) {
        $txtOutput.= $M3['id'].'Temperatura: '.$M3['temperatura'].' Humedad:'.$M3['temperatura'].' Fecha'.$M3['fecha'].' Hora '.$M3['hora'].'<hr>';
    }
}else{
    $txtOutput="No se encontraron datos";   
}
echo $txtOutput;
```

Answer (score -1):

Tienes un limit 1 en la consulta, por eso solo te sale un resultado. Además, deberías preparar la consulta y pasar los parámetros o al menos escaparlos antes de concatenar.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->execute([':id' => $id]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Los parámetros los puedes poner con con dos puntos ":" y un nombre o con un interrogante "?" `'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?`. Si usas el interrogante al array que pasas a execute no le pones claves.

Comment: En el ejemplo si usaba fetchColumn en vez de RowCount no mostraba ningun registro pese que habia al menos uno, el limit ya lo habia dejado con otros valores y siempre me mostraba con un valor menos del que habia en la tabla. Leere lo de preparar la consulta

Comment: Actualizo la respuesta para ponerte un ejemplo de preparar consultas. ¿La consulta que usas es la que tienes en la pregunta?

Comment: Si sabes cual es la entrada exacta que no te muestra coméntala y pon los datos de filtrado ¿puede ser que no cumpla la condición? En la pregunta entendí que el código que te daba todos menos uno era otro distinto. Lo que hay en la pregunta solo te puede mostrar un entrada